# How do I get osgeo4w apache install to allow my regular windows account access?

Tags: apache, qgis-server

I have just installed QGIS server on my Windows 7 machine. The installation went fine after some googling to find all the bits and pieces that needed to be done and I can fetch my get capabilities document and see the test.qgs project I added to the server.

However I can't seem to successfully connect to the service in QGIS, I get the error below.

[image]

Is there something on the apache configuration that I have missed which would allow or deny users access to the service?

Thanks

**EDIT**: *Platform: Windows 7, and installed Apache through the OSGEO4W Installer.* Okay so I installed apache and QGIS Server through an admin account which was setup by our service desk then it was taken away after the install. So when I run QGIS under my normal account I get the error in the above picture. I asked for the admin account again, chose to open QGIS by going "Run as administrator" and everything worked just fine. I could connect to the wms and see my test service. How do I modify apache to allow access for my regular windows account?

Ando

Comment: It sounds like it is working through a web browser OK. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah - on my machine to localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh - Sorry I may not have added all the necessary information in my original question. But here are the details of what worked for me.

I was using a httpProxy in QGIS. In the section "Exclude URLs (starting with)" I added the server name I was trying to access and that solved the access issue.

@dakcarto, I appreciate the speedy assistance you were able to offer.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured. Good to know about the proxy settings possibly affecting the server that way.

Answer (score 1):

In the QGIS WMS connection dialogue there is  “Ignore GetMap URI …” and “Ignore GetFeature URI …”. Checking these options might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

3a. Apache (2.2.14-4 from OSGeo4W) **does not have any default IP/port set** and it fails to start. Edit the file

```
c:/osgeo4w/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

and change

Listen @apache_port_number@

to your needs, for example, to listen on port 80,use

Listen 80

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial

Comment: Ando mentioned "can fetch my get capabilities document and see the test.qgs project I added to the server." So, I think Apache is already running, and a map is being served. Just fails to connect from within QGIS.

Comment: That's correct dakcarto. Apache is operating through port 80

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, since I haven't used OSGeo4W yet (Mac and Linux, usually), but it looks like you have not defined a MAP parameter in your WMS configuration's URL. According to the [MAP parameter description](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial#Map-parameter):

> "If not specified, QGIS searches for .qgs files in the directory where the server executable is located."

So I think Apache's user doesn't have permission to serve from wherever the qgis_mapserv binary is located.

Try adding the MAP parameter and path to the WMS connection URL ( without the brackets [ ] ):

```
http://localhost/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=[c:/path/to/your/map.qgs]
```

Comment: Again that works fine in the browser but will not load the WMS into QGIS. I've never had a problem adding a WMS to QGIS server before, so I think it is definitely something in my apache setup.

Comment: The last thing I can think of, as far as QGIS is concerned, is underdark's answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/why-does-the-qgis-server-wms-layer-not-load-in-qgis-desktop  But I don't see what that would fix, permission-wise. Really curious that it works in a browser but not via QGIS.

Comment: Hey Dakcarto - I modified the above question to more accurately reflect the issue. I installed the application from the start under an administrative account and then I was demoted back to a regular user. I am thinking this is what has stuffed me up.